# Query the Active Directory an return the OU name and last boot time for computers

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I've adapted a query (originally from [here](https://gist.github.com/rob-murray/4491737/raw/4ef98331d8d2fbe2504b106453d00ca1669ab009/ad-computer-search.vbs)) to grab the name and OS of a computer in the Active Director for a specific domain.

Is there a way, using this technique, of also outputting the **name of the OU** that the computer resides in, and the **last time it was booted/connected to the AD**? Thanks.

```
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT Name, operatingSystem FROM " & _
    "'LDAP://" & strDomain & "' " & _
    "WHERE objectClass='computer' " & _
    "AND (operatingSystem = 'Windows 2000 Professional' " & _
    "OR operatingSystem = 'Windows XP Professional') " & _
    "ORDER BY Name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your select

```
SELECT Name, operatingSystem, Adspath, lastLogonTimeStamp FROM
```

Then add this

```
Set objDate = objRecordset.Fields("lastLogonTimeStamp").Value
dtmDate = "n/a"
lngHigh = objDate.HighPart
lngLow = objDate.LowPart
If (lngLow < 0) Then
    lngHigh = lngHigh + 1
End If
If (lngHigh = 0) And (lngLow = 0) Then
    dtmDate = "n/a"
Else
    dtmDate = #1/1/1601# + (((lngHigh * (2 ^ 32)) _
    + lngLow)/600000000)/1440
End If
```

`objRecordSet.Fields("Adspath")` is the Distinguished Name and `dtmDate` is the last logon date